# While using Literature references in LyX provided by BibDesk on Mac OS 10.8 capital letters are getting confused

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

On my Mac I am working with BibDesk to manage my literature references in LyX. Everything works just fine. Except for the following.

In BibDesk I added a certain book with a german title in which capital letters appear and it looks this way.

[image: BibDesk Screenshot]

After setting up lyx the citation in the bibliography section of my document appears this way.

[image: LyX Screenshot]

Somehow the letters *f* in the word *Funktionen* and the *M* in the word *Modulformen* were transformed to lower case, which is wrong and clearly not the same as I entered them in BibDesk.

Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: As explained in the answers below this due to `bibtex`'s parsing features.  This difficulty of markup does not occur with `biblatex/biber` and could be a reason to swap to their bibliography mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the letters that you would like preserved as uppercase in brackets, {}. If you would like to preserve the whole title, put everything within the extra pair of brackets:

```
{{Elliptische Funktionen und Modulformen}}
```

egreg points out in a comment to this answer that the following is better:

```
title={Elliptische {Funktionen} und {Modulformen}}
```

Note that there are reasons why the default behavior is what it is. There is a lot of information on this topic.

Comment: This saves in keystrokes, but I believe that `title={Elliptische {Funktionen} und {Modulformen}}` is better.

Comment: @egreg Good to know. And is `title={Elliptische {F}unktionen und {M}odulformen}` even better? I don't know what the differences are. Is there source where I can read up on this?

Comment: No, using `{F}unktionen` won't kern between the "F" and the "u", which might be worse for words starting with "To", for instance.

Comment: @egreg Ah, that makes sense.